# How to execute a simple Mysql SELECT DATEDIFF() in Zend Framework 1.x

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want to execute a simple query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), '2015-02-05');
```

How to execute this query in Zend Framework 1.x?

```
$sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), '2015-02-05')";
$db->fetchRow($sql);
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), '2015-02-05')";
$db->fetchRow($sql);
```

I checked the Zend manual, there are some other functions like `fetchCol()`, but in my project, there is no such a method, just have `fetchAll()`, `fetchRow()`.

I am actually using a Zend Framework extension which is built upon Zend Framework, and it is in the 'lib' folder of the project. I guess this is why I can only use `fetchAll()`, `fetchRow()`.

Anyone know how to execute such a simple query in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 0):

to get value from current position

```
    $sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), '2015-02-05') as dd";
    $r = $db->query($sql)->fetchColumn();
```

result: 346

---

to get array from current position

```
    $sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), '2015-02-05') as dd";
    $r = $db->query($sql)->fetch();
```

result: ['dd':346]

---

to get object from current position

```
    $sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), '2015-02-05') as dd";
    $r = $db->query($sql)->fetchObject('stdClass');
```

result: {'dd':346}

---

to get all rows

```
    $sql = "SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), '2015-02-05') as dd";
    $r = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```

result: [0:['dd':346]]